# Change in \lstdefinelanguage the font?

Tags: fonts, listings, languages

Im using `\lstdefinelanguage` to add some new languages. Now everything is fine, I just would like to add another font to my language. I would like to use **inconsolata**.

I have now this:

```
%...
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\lstdefinelanguage{Scala}
{
  %...
  basicstyle=\small %what else do i have to add to use inconsolata?
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loading the `inconsolata` package, the monospaced font is redefined, so it's enough to add `\ttfamily` (you could also access the font using `\fontfamily{fi4}\selectfont`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\lstdefinelanguage{Scala}
{
  %...
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Scala]
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world!")
    }
  }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is working. Im just asking myself why "fi4"? And also, how to add the same font in a bold format?

Comment: Shouldn't `basicstyle=\ttfamily\small` suffice?

Comment: @LissyA unfortunately the `inconsolata` package doesn't offer a bold version of the font.

Comment: @cgnieder you're absolutely right; I'll edit the answer. Thank you.